# Is there an analog of Ginga style in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics

Ginga is a highly creative and elegant form of playing soccer or football. It was the playing style of legendary footballers like Pele and Garrincha.

What I want to know is whether there is a similar form or problem solving methodology in mathematics which can be rightly referred to as the "Ginga style" of doing mathematical sciences?

Comment: elegance fades in the presence of greater skill and desire.  So if you're asking about different methods of proving a theorem, first find any proof that is valid.

Comment: You may want to google "Street-Fighting Mathematics".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ginga" refers to the game style full of surprise moves or tricks, it is not really a methodology. I suppose solving [Olympiad style math problems](http://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/misc/olympiad-vs-higher-math) would be a loose analog. However, it is not uncontroversially admired, Terence Tao warns, for example:

> "*But mathematical competitions are very different activities from mathematical learning or mathematical research; don’t expect the problems you get in, say, graduate study, to have the same cut-and-dried, neat flavour that an Olympiad problem does. (While individual steps in the solution might be able to be finished off quickly by someone with Olympiad training, the majority of the solution is likely to require instead the much more patient and lengthy process of reading the literature, applying known techniques, trying model problems or special cases, looking for counterexamples, and so forth.)*"

Still, it worked out for Tao, an International Math Olympiad gold winner at 13 he went on to become a Fields medalist (mathematical "Nobel" winner) at 31. The famous older examples at a higher level include the style of "trickster" problem-solvers like [Ramanujan](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2016/04/who-was-ramanujan) with his neat and unexpected identities, or versatile [Paul Erdős](https://theconversation.com/the-man-who-turned-coffee-into-theorems-16008). Grothendieck was famously of the diametrically opposite stylistic persuasion, promoting the systematic "rising sea" approach instead:

> "*The unknown thing to be known appeared to me as some stretch of earth or
>   hard marl, resisting penetration... the sea advances insensibly in silence, nothing seems to happen, nothing moves, the water is so far off you hardly hear it... yet it finally surrounds the resistant substance*". [Quoted from [MacLarty's The Rising Sea: Grothendieck on simplicity and generality](http://www.landsburg.com/grothendieck/mclarty1.pdf)]

Grothendieck even complained that Deligne, his student, proved the famous Weil conjectures with a "trick" instead of raising the sea around them.